# Python: Convert n-tuple to x-tuple where x < n

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

The question is pretty straightforward (unlike the title). I have a tuple of the type:

```
p = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
# I refer to this as a 6-tuple but p could be an n-tuple
```

I need to convert this into a smaller tuple like:

```
(a, b) = p
```

such that `a <- 1` and `b <- (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

**EDIT:**

I need code for Python v2.7. Also, I should have mentioned that there are ways to do it but I am looking for something natural and something where I don't need to deal with indices. For example.

```
a, b, c, d, e = p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5:]
```

is not desired.

**EDIT 2:**

In the above example, a is an integer whereas b is our new tuple. The idea behind n-tuple to x-tuple is that the length of the new tuple is smaller than the original one. In the following example we have 0-tuples (ints):

```
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
```

However, if it's the following:

```
a, b, c, d = (1, 2, 3)
```

then, we have `a <- 1, b <- 2, c <-3, d <- None/Nothing`.

Comment: So `a` isn't supposed to be a tuple afterwards? Is it always a single item that's split from the rest?

Comment: If it was a = p, then yes 'a' would have been a tuple. But in this case no. What is essentially happening is that the length of the tuple is decreasing. At some point if the length of the tuple is the same as the number of assignments then at the end, there will be no tuple; just an integer.

Comment: Are you sure you really want tuples for this? Tuples are typically used when you know exactly how many elements they have and what each of them represent. What you have sounds a lot more like a list.

Comment: Please state your requirements explicitly. Now that you've added the fact that a) you don't want an index based approach, and b) you might want to split into more than two segments (how many?), please also specify whether the initial segments are ever supposed to contain more than one item each.

Comment: No. The example clearly states that. I am sorry I wasn't very explicit; but I seem to have given the idea that approach needs to be very natural and should not be based on the number of assignments or the length of the tuple; but that's my bad. I should have been explicit.

Comment: @kqr, it does not matter if it's tuples or lists in this case. The RHS will be constant anyway.

Comment: @flippex17 It does matter for the available operations you can perform on the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general solution:

```
def split_after(lst, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield lst[i]
    yield lst[n:]
```

Result:

```
>>> a,b,n = split_after(p,2)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> n
(3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> l = list(split_after(p,3))
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6)]
```

So you need to know how many items you have on the left-hand side and tell that to the function (because it can't tell that by itself, unlike what the extended tuple unpacking syntax in Python 3 allows you to do).

Comment: I am voting this as the answer as it's the best that can be done. I had something very similar but I was wondering if there was something as easy as the example for Python3. Nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
a, b = p[0], p[1:]
```

This is example

```
>>> p = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> a, b = p[0], p[1:]
>>> a
1
>>> b
(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit. I don't want something that rigid. I can obviously deal with indices but I don't want that.

Comment: @flippex17 i see. i think the answer of Tim Pietzcker is helpful

Comment: @flippex17: I removed it because it wasn't doing what you wanted it to do. Hold on a second.

Comment: @TimPietzcker got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3, this is trivial using the [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) syntax:

```
>>> p = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> a, *b = p
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`b` gets made into a list since the RHS can be any iterable, but you can do `b = tuple(b)` if you really need it to be exactly a tuple.

This does vary slightly from your later examples:

```
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
```

This syntax is already legal in Python 2, and will do the right thing in the case that the LHS and the RHS have the same number of items. This is the *only* case that will work in Python 2 without playing with indexing.

Using a `*` will also work here in Python 3, but the variable you attach it to will *always* be a list - even if it only has one item:

```
>>> a,b,*c = (1, 2, 3)
>>> c
[3]
```

But in your last example, it will do roughly what you want:

```
a, b, c, *d = (1, 2, 3)
>>> d
[]
```

ie, `d` is an empty list rather than `None`.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post. This is not intended for Python 3 or above.

Comment: Too bad, this seems to be closest to what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Too bad, you are right. I believe if it was `a, b, *c = p`, `a <- 2`, `b <- 3` and `c <- (4, 5, 6)`. I don't have Python3 so I cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2 the RHS must unpack to the correct number of items to match the LHS. You can avoid indices with hacks like this. But you still need knowledge of the number of items to unpack there.

```
>>> p = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> a, b = (lambda a, *b:(a, b))(*p)
>>> a
1
>>> b
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: This looks seriously cool, especially because I don't get how it works :)

Comment: OK, and for "larger" tuples, you'd need to extend it like `a, b, c = (lambda a, b, *c:(a, b, c))(*p)`. I'm starting to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

This will recursively split a list based off of a list of split indices.

```
def split(lis, splits):
    if not splits:
         return [lis]
    new_splits = [s - splits[0] for s in splits[1:]]
    return [lis[:splits[0]]] + split(lis[splits[0]:], new_splits)
```

### Usage

```
>>> split([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2])
    [[1,2], [3,4,5,6]]

>>> split([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4])
    [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

>>> split([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,8])
    [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], []]
```

Which you can use like this:

```
>>> a,b,c,d = split([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,8])
```